# Read from file every time or load into array Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to know if my idea is a good one.

Im putting together a web server that streams html file js file css file, kind of static web server.

As it been static i was thinking that i only need to really read the file one and then load it into an array at start to cut down on file reads when clients request.

something like this kind of code

```
var tttt = []


var server = http.createServer();
server.on("request",function(request, response){
    var etret = '/home/bob/node-show/big-file.js';

    var setHeader = function(file){

        return {
            'Content-Type': MIME.mime(file),
            'Transfer-Encoding':'chunked',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive'
        };

    }
    if (!tttt[path.basename(etret)]) {
        tttt[path.basename(etret)] = []

        var test = fs.createReadStream(etret)
        test.setEncoding('ascii')
        test.on('data', function(data){
            console.log(data)
            tttt[path.basename(etret)].push(data)
        });
        test.on('close', function(data){
            console.log('sadsad')
            response.writeHead(200, setHeader(etret))
            console.log(tttt[path.basename(etret)].length)
            for (var i = 0; i < tttt[path.basename(etret)].length; i++) {
                response.write(tttt[path.basename(etret)][i])
            };
            var erw = 0
            for (var f = 0; f < tttt[path.basename(etret)].length; f++) {
                erw = (erw + tttt[path.basename(etret)][f].length)
            }
            console.log(erw)
            response.end()
        });
    }else{
        response.writeHead(200, setHeader(etret))
        console.log(tttt[path.basename(etret)].length)
        for (var i = 0; i < tttt[path.basename(etret)].length; i++) {
            response.write(tttt[path.basename(etret)][i])
        };
        var erw = 0
        for (var f = 0; f < tttt[path.basename(etret)].length; f++) {
            erw = (erw + tttt[path.basename(etret)][f].length)
        }
        console.log(erw)
        response.end()
        console.dir(server.connections)
    }
    //return _fontEnd(request, response);
}).listen(8000, function(){
    console.log('HTTP server up');
});
```

big-file.js been about 500kb could it be a good idea to load maybe 50 files into memory to save reads from the hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

Caching (of static files) in general is a common practice in [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html) and also node.js based [Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) supports caching. You can see the cost of I/O between disk and RAM in [this](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/) article.